# Restructure urls using .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I need to convert links such as

`http://www.example.co.uk/blog/archive.php?date=2012-05`

to

`http://www.example.co.uk/blog/archive/2012/05/`

using php or .htaccess file.

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/archive/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ http://www.example.co.uk/blog/archive.php?date=$1-$2 [NC]
```

Ive have tried this but not having any luck.  Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get a 404 when accessing the url? Is there anything else in the htaccess? Code looks fine to me.

Comment: Hi Gerben nothing, the code is ignored the only thing i could think of is that rewrite mod is not enabled but i would have no idea how to check this.

Comment: Haven't you missed out the word archive? I don't think your pattern matches

Comment: "archive" ... if you see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that to the example above but is in my .htaccess file, have updated code above.

Comment: What directory should the .htaccess file go in? blog or top directory?

Comment: What version of apache are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog/archive/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ blog/archive.php?date=$1-$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I get Internal Server Error 500 - I remove the top line server error goes but still doesn't work.

Comment: I have posted it after testing it on my Apache. Can you please check error.log of Apache and see what the actual error is? As a side note pls post your latest .htaccess in your question.